# order by 1.99.10 and 1.99.9 sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Sorry about my mistake, I should provide the real sample for the question, my ID included characters inside:

sample code:

```
select ID from student order by ID

Expected output from mine          but system output
-------------------------          -----------------
JAD.1.99.9                             JAD.1.99.10
JAD.1.99.10                            JAD.1.99.9
```

and this `ID` is of `nvarchar` type.

Comment: The system output is the normal expected behavior when sorting by text values. They are not numbers. Character "1" precedes character "9".

Comment: Follow this link may be you will get some idea..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/119730/how-do-i-sort-a-varchar-column-in-sql-server-that-contains-numbers

Comment: possible duplicate of [How Can I Sort A 'Version Number' Column Generically Using a SQL Server Query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3474870/how-can-i-sort-a-version-number-column-generically-using-a-sql-server-query)

Answer (score 14):

[Yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16575406/284240) there was a similar question where i have learned that you can use [`hierarchyid`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677290.aspx) for version sorting(if you use at least SQL-Server 2008):

```
SELECT id 
FROM   student 
ORDER  BY Cast('/' + Replace(id, '.', '/') + '/' AS HIERARCHYID)
```

[**DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e3cb1/1/0)

Comment: Thank Tim...your answer is perfect....its improving knowledge.......in right way...

Comment: +1 Also you can use ORDER BY clause without replace function: ORDER BY Cast('/' + id + '/' AS HIERARCHYID). Demo:http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e3cb1/13

Answer (score -2):

You need to order by the substring of the part after any dot. This is going to be a DB specific SQL query and since you didn't mention which one you're using I can't give a detailed SQL example.

This is how you can cast a decimals values

http://www.w3resource.com/sql/aggregate-functions/avg-decimal-places-using-cast-within-avg.php

The answer from Tim is best..

But I am giving one more solution for order varchar values --

```
SELECT id 
FROM   student 
ORDER  BY ID desc
```

Comment: That would not return what user2098512 wants

Comment: You cannot reverse the order just because OP's result was ordered wrong. Now you are always sorting descending even if the id's would be `1.99.8` and `1.99.9`. This is also not a version sort. Just test it with `1.1.1` and `2.1` which starts with `2.1`.

Comment: Please see this example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c3fbc/1 to understand why this answer is simply wrong. I cannot understand this was upvoted 3 times.